# After github "merge pull request " action, all commits from the feature branch and a new merge commit appearing on the develop branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Develop branch looks like

```
Develop
  |- Commit 1
```

Create feature branch off develop git checkout -b feature origin/develop

```
Feature 
  |- Commit 1
  |- Commit 2  (New commit)
  |- Commit 3  (New Commit)
```

After that created a PR with two commits.
Use a GitHub Merge pull request button to merge
After merging the commit history of Develop looks like

```
Develop
  |- Commit 1
  |- Commit 2
  |- Commit 3
  |- Merged pull request #1 from user/branch/name
```

Any reason why commit 2 & 3 appearing in the history of Develop

Comment: You need to do/enable [squash merging](https://github.blog/2016-04-01-squash-your-commits/) on Github if you want this behavior.

Comment: Udit expected to see commit 2 & 3

Comment: Any reason? This is the standard git merge result (that you specifically asked for, btw). Merging means creating a new node in the tree to "bind" some (sometimes more than 2) commits together. The "expected" result you describe seems indeed to be a squash (like Kent rightfully linked), but note that it has its own caveats. Don't hesitate to read more on the subject, this is an important basic in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge commit is created to show you what was added to the current branch from other branches.

If you enable graph display feature, then the merge commit will make more sense since it will show you that it "combined" (merged) two paths: commit 1 and commits 2-3.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Totally agree with the graph but when I do git log with master i see commit 2, commit 3 and merge commit. is that expected?

Comment: @touchchandra Yes, it is expected. You can do: `git log --author=<name> --no-merges` to ignore the merge commits, for the same results I believe this does: `git log --first-parent`